# Termo técnico "Forgetting Curve" em português

Tags: tradução-inglês, expressões-equivalentes, termos-em-inglês

Qual a melhor tradução do termo técnico `Forgetting Curve` para Português?

O contexto é o termo em inglês `Forgetting Curve` conforme exatamente mencionado em https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetting_curve, porém não temos uma entrada na wikipedia PT.

Por ser um termo técnico, é importante que haja um cuidado maior.

---

Comentário extra: notem que há uma suave diferença entre "Curva **de** Esquecimento" e "Curva **do** Esquecimento", por exemplo, a segunda parece ser mais popular em buscas no Google (por isso até seria a que eu normalmente escolheria) porém não sei dizer se ela seria a a tradução do termo ideal no português.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Portugal: trabalho acadêmico

**curva de esquecimento**

> Há 120 anos Ebbinghaus (1885/1964) provou este facto ao determinar a
>   sua famosa **curva de esquecimento** que descrevia o declínio progressivo de aprendizagens verbais adquiridas a um critério de 100% com a passagem do tempo. Desde então muitos outros investigadores replicaram este efeito (e.g., McGeoch, 1932; Peterson e Peterson, 1959) de que se destaca mais recentemente o famoso estudo de Bahrick (1984) sobre a **curva de esquecimento** do espanhol aprendido ao longo de intervalos de retenção que variavam do presente até cerca de 50 anos antes. Ver ainda Conway, Cohen, e Stanhope
>   (1991); Pinto (1989); Pinto e Oliveira (1991).

Brazil: blog, curva **do esquecimento**

> A curva do esquecimento está atuando enquanto você lê este texto.
>
> Significa que algo absolutamente normal está ocorrendo com você neste
>   exato momento: você está esquecendo algum conteúdo já estudado, não
>   importa se o estudo foi realizado há algumas horas, ontem ou há
>   algumas semanas.

Brazil: origem do termo por Wagner Cassimiro

> A Curva de Esquecimento é uma generalização de sua descoberta [Ebbinghaus] e pode ser interpretada da seguinte forma. No momento em que estamos aprendendo, basicamente conseguiremos resgatar toda a informação que queremos. Após 20 minutos, do conteúdo visto, retemos 58%, o que quer dizer que já teremos esquecido 42% destas informações.  Após 1 hora esse número cai para 44% e após 9 horas, conseguiremos resgatar apenas 36% da informação.
>
> [Cassimiro: de esquecimento](http://espresso3.com.br/a-curva-de-esquecimento-de-ebbinghaus/)

Pessoalmente, prefiro **de esquecimento**, porque "do" sugere que o esquecimento pertence à curva......aula de inglês, e não aula do inglês [que sugere que não era aula do português que mora na minha rua].

A expressão "a curva de demanda" usada em economia se diz nos dois lados do Atlântico. A curva de esquecimento se formaria da mesma maneira para significar o assunto de que se trata.

[do esquecimento](https://estudoesquematizado.com.br/curva-do-esquecimento/)

[curva do esquecimento](https://www.fpce.up.pt/docentes/acpinto/artigos/22_amancio.pdf)

Comment: Concordo com "**de** esquecimento".

Comment: Curva *do* esquecimento tende a ser a mais usada. Uma busca no google pelos dois termos, no com "do" o Google até associa a da wikipedia em inglês e da um snippet de significado. Porém intuitivamente parece que "de" seria o mais apropriado. Pergunto isso porque talvez no futuro eu acabe até criando uma entrada na wikipedia com esboço de tradução.

Comment: Talvez eu demore um pouco para marcar essa resposta (ou alguma outra) como aceita. Não que a resposta esteja ruim, mas sim que se for viável eu aplique recompensa como fiz com outra pergunta que está em aberto

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Não se preocupa. Não tou nem aí. Mas pessoalmente, não vejo como se poderia discordar do que coloquei. Parece que abrange tudo que a pergunta abrange.